# loop through cursor's data and compare for another table's value sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle, toad

I have two tables. I want to get desc from Table 2 after following steps:
1. Select name from Table1 where type = 'animal';
2. loop through each names from 1. and check for Table2 i.e o_name = name;
3. Then check if desc exist for that o_name.
4. If desc doesnot exist then insert 'pet' for that record on Table2.

How do I do it? For now I have a cursor that has name from Table1. I am thinking to loop through the cursor's record but beyond that I am not being able to do. Please suggest me:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR DATA is
        SELECT name 
        FROM Table1
        where type='animal';    
BEGIN
     FOR C IN DATA LOOP
        // After this what can I do?? I cannot do select into because there will be
        // multiple rows
     END LOOP;   
END;
```

/

```
Table1:
id | name  | type
---| ----  | -----
  1| Apple | food
  2| Ball  | game
  3| Cat   | animal
  4| Cow   | animal
  5| Ball  | game

   Table2:
o_name | desc
    ---| ----
  Apple| eat  
    Cat| pet
    Cow|
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it with a cursor?

Comment: @rjdevereux Hi Rj Can we do it without cursor?

Comment: Why do you need to loop through table1. It is known in advance that name will be `Cat`. So why not just get cats from table2 directly? It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Usually you would do something like `SELECT a.id, a.name, b.desc FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.name = b.o_name WHERE a.name = 'Cat' ORDER BY a.id, b.desc`. But as I said before, if you only need to get cats it seems pointless to use table1, unless you need other columns from it.

Comment: @Olivier I have just updated the question. Please take a look at it.

Comment: I don't understand - are you looking for help on a SELECT statement (displaying a set of result rows), or are you looking to actually UPDATE the rows in Table2 with the description ('pet' in your example)? These are different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still can do this as query and don't need a cursor. Note that databases are optimized for working on sets of records, and that's what SQL queries do. Cursors should only be used if other strategies do not work.

```
UPDATE Table2
SET "desc" = 'pet'
WHERE
    "desc" IS NULL AND
    o_name IN (SELECT name FROM Table1 WHERE "type" = 'animal')
```

Note that `DESC` and `TYPE` are [reserved words in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm), therefore I enclosed them in double quotes. Single quotes are used to enclose text literals (strings) in Oracle.